# cannot allocate vector of size 2.5 Gb in R Studio

Tags: r

I get this error "**Error: cannot allocate vector of size 2.5 Gb**" when i execute missforest to impute missing values in the dataframe.

My laptop has 16gb ram, but it is not able to allocate 2.5gb. Please check my session info.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
```

memory limit,

```
> memory.limit()
[1] 16235
> gc()
            used   (Mb) gc trigger    (Mb)   max used    (Mb)
Ncells   2911205  155.5    4282075   228.7    4282075   228.7
Vcells 291474489 2223.8 1694578986 12928.7 2013536838 15362.1
```

Please help me solve this issue.

Thanks
sjb

Comment: Can you allocate a vector of size 2 GB?

Comment: @collapsar can not even allocate a vector size of 2.5gb

Comment: @Jaap Please remove duplicate tag for this question, as the solution provided in the above question addresses how to use memory efficiently but my problem is my has 16gb ram and not able to allocate vector of size 1gb. Thanks

Comment: No it is a duplicate. R only reports the last allocation attempted. If you have 16G spare, allocate 15.9 then allocate 0.2 it will say it can’t allocate 0.2.

Comment: @Hugh thanks for your reply. Is there any specific solution for this error?.